# error in a recursively-called make doesn't stop the calling make

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a makefile that loops over all child directories that have files called `Makefile` in them, and runs a new `make` in that directory with my current target.  It works fine when it works.

However, if the child `make` process finds an error it stops...  but my calling `make` doesn't.  The  calling make continues to run, giving a false impression it is working.  How can I make the calling make halt in this case?

```
# Make the same target in all subdirectories with a Makefile.
SubMakefiles    = $(shell find -L . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name Makefile)
SubMakeDirs     = $(filter-out ./,$(dir $(SubMakefiles)))

clean depend all::
        @for dir in $(SubMakeDirs); do \
            make -C $$dir $@
        done
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without changing your targeting, you can capture the return value of one or more commands in `sh` with parenthesis, and exit with their error code should there be an error code, as follows:

```
# Make the same target in all subdirectories with a Makefile.
SubMakefiles    = $(shell find -L . -maxdepth 2 -type f -name Makefile)
SubMakeDirs     = $(filter-out ./,$(dir $(SubMakefiles)))

clean depend all::
        @for dir in $(SubMakeDirs); do \
            ( make -C $$dir $@ ) || exit $$?; \
        done
```

Answer (score 0):

Ultimately I settled on the following approach.   Since the recursive `make` is run as a command directly by make, any error code produced will cause the master make to abort as well.

Walkthrough: we recurse to any sub-directory with a `Makefile` in it.
`MAKECMDGOALS` is a gmake-managed variable holding the command goal.  A little counterintuitively, this top-level makefile says that whatever command you're trying to run depends on all the subdirectories with makefiles, and the rule to "create" those subdirectories (of course they already exist, but gmake isn't specifically aware of that) it recursively runs the same command in the subdirectory (specified with `-C`).

```
SUBDIRS = ${sort ${dir ${wildcard */Makefile}}}

all $(MAKECMDGOALS):: $(SUBDIRS)

.PHONY: $(SUBDIRS)

$(SUBDIRS)::
        $(MAKE) --no-print-directory -C $@ $(MAKECMDGOALS)
```